# Rxjs: Execute code and emit value on completion of Observable

Tags: rxjs

How can I execute some code and emit a final value when an Observable completes?

RxJS provides an `endWith` operator, which takes a value to emit on completion. I however want to pass in a `valueProvider` function, which should only be executed when my `src$` Observable completes returning a final value that should be emitted.

```js
const mapped$ = src$.pipe(
 //only on completion
  endWithCallback(() => {
   const endParam= this.getSomething();
   return endValue;
  }),
);
```

Off course, the above code does not work. How can I achieve something like this?

Comment: If you want to execute some code on completion the call that inside `.subscribe` complete callback which is the third parameter of `subscribe` method. Can you explain your question a bit more?

Comment: Rxjs already provides an endWith operator, which takes value to emit on completion. I want to provide valueProvider function, which will execute on completion of src$ and create a value to emit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `concat` and `defer` to append an Observable to your source whose inner code is executed after the source completes.

```js
concat(src$, defer(() => of(getLast())))
```

You could also create an operator that does it.

```js
src$.pipe(withLast(getLast))

// 1. emits the same type as source
export function withLast<T>(getLast: () => T): MonoTypeOperatorFunction<T> {
  return (source: Observable<T>) => concat(source, defer(() => of(getLast())));
}

// 2. emits a different type than source
export function withLastAs<T, R>(getLast: () => R): OperatorFunction<T, R> {
  return (source: Observable<T>) => source.lift.call(
    concat(source, defer(() => of(getLast())))
  );
}
```

---

`getLast` includes the code you want to execute when your source completes and returns a value that will be emitted last.

```
function getLast(): any {
  console.log('on last');
  const endParam = this.getSomething();
  return endValue;
}
```

Comment: Nice. You are a savior :)